# OAuth::Unauthorized (403 Forbidden) dropbox-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dropbox-api

I am getting an error unauthorize on the callback in this line:

request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_token])

below is my controller code:

```
def new
   consumer      = Dropbox::API::OAuth.consumer(:authorize)
   request_token = consumer.get_request_token
   @dropbox_auth = request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => dropbox_callback_url)
end
```

**callback:**

```
def dropbox_callback
   consumer      = Dropbox::API::OAuth.consumer(:authorize)
   request_token = consumer.get_request_token
   request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_token]) **here is the line where I am getting the error**

   client = Dropbox::API::Client.new :token => token, :secret => secret
end
```

Comment: There's an example of how someone has done [OAuth with dropbox in Rails here](http://tomash.wrug.eu/2012/09/04/integrating-with-dropbox-api-for-fun-and-profit.html).  Seems to me that somewhere in the call you would need to pass the consumer secret.

Comment: that's it sir. thanks!
I need these:
`session[:request_token]`
`session[:request_token_secret]`